# R igraph: Fast shortest path

Tags: r, igraph, shortest-path, network-analysis

I'm writing a script to calculate shortest paths between 352k pairs of 983 nodes, for which I'm currently using igraph's shortest.paths function. It currently takes around 35 seconds, which isn't practical for my application - I'd ideally need it down to around 5 seconds but I'm not sure if this is feasible.

The main inefficiency of shortest.paths that I can think of is that it's calculating shortest paths for every single possible node pair (all 966k).

Does anyone know of a faster way of doing this (including any reasonable pre-processing I could do, or a way of getting the algorithm to only run on the node pairs I need it for?

Thanks

**Example**

```
set.seed(1)
nodes <- c(1:1000)
edgelist <- expand.grid(nodes,nodes) %>%
  mutate(weight = runif(nrow(.))) %>%
  arrange(weight) %>%
  slice(1:350000)

graph <- edgelist %>%
  select(c(1,2)) %>%
  as.matrix(.) %>%
  graph_from_edgelist(., directed = F)

graph <- set.edge.attribute(graph, "weight", index=E(graph), edgelist$weight)

start <- Sys.time()
s.paths <- shortest.paths(graph,
                          algorithm = "dijkstra")
Sys.time() - start
```

Runtime: 18s

In this example, I only actually want the 350k node-pairs in the edgelist, but it's calculating all 1 million possible pairs. I can extract the ones I want easily, but I'm wondering whether I can get the run time down by somehow getting it to only calculate the distances for the pairs I actually need (or by any other means).

Comment: at a quick glance it looks like `shortest_paths` takes `from` and `to` arguments ... ?? Can you give us a [mcve] (i.e. define a graph for us)?

Comment: Sorry, just added one in so you can see what I'm talking about

Comment: The algorithm does not work in terms of pairs, but in terms of sources. I.e., one step computes distances from one source vertex to all other vertices. In other words, a smaller `from` will speed up the calculation, but a smaller `to` will not.

Comment: Note that choosing `algorithm = "dijkstra"` for an unweighted graph does not do anything.

Comment: Can you show a reproducible example? I was unable to produce a graph with 1000 vertices on which the calculation of the full distance matrix would take more than 5 seconds. In the unweighted case (which your current example shows), the calculation is well below 1 second (around 0.1 s).

Comment: Thanks, I've just replaced my example with fuller one. My actual graph is weighted, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Here `shortest.paths` is equivalent to `distances`, which yields a matrix (type `?distances` to see the examples there)

For you solution, you could use `diag` like below to retrieve the three distances you are after:

```
diag(s.paths)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I should have been clearer. The problem I'm having isn't extracting the correct distances, it's increasing the speed of the calculation. I'm basically doing it the way you suggested already, but on a large graph it's quite slow. Getting it to calculate only the necessary distances was just an idea for a way of speeding it up